# Visual Studio: Library output path flexibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

Okay, here's the problem.
I have 2 projects. One is the main project (executable), the other one is a library.

- MyNameSpace.Libraries.TheHolyMefLibrary
- MyNameSpace.TheProduct

The default output path of both projects is `bin\Debug\`, so when I compile the main application, in the debug folder I can find both the Executable, as well as the library.

Now, I would like to have the following output:

- bin\Debug\MyExecutable.exe
- bin\Debug\plugins\TheHolyMefLibrary.dll

But when I change the output path of the library to `bin\Debug\plugins\`, the compiler still creates the following output

- bin\Debug\MyExecutable.exe
- bin\Debug\TheHolyMefLibrary.dll

How can I ensure that, no matter which project links to the library, it's always going to be in a subfolder of the output path from the main assembly, even in setup solutions?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I think the best way is to create a `Post-build script` where you move your linked assembly DLL to the plugins folder. You can find the post-build script editor when you right click the application project file and select `Properties` and then go to the `Build Events` tab. To create the build script you can use `CMD` commands like for example the `MOVE` command in your case or `XCOPY`.

Comment: So there's no 'official' way to solve this? I mean, in other projects I have sometimes > 20 libraries, so the assembly directory becomes easiliy very messy.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'Copy Local' property of the referenced assembly to False to stop it being copied to your main project's bin folder.